# Using autocert for multiple subdomains and ip addresses via DNS

Tags: ssl, go, dns

I have two separate servers using the same domain name with separate prefixes, one doing some app stuff and one doing filesharing. Using the `autocert` package how can I just configure the cert manager to produce a certificate that I can use on both servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add both domains to the cert manager white list:

```
certManager := autocert.Manager{
            Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
            HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist("domain.me", "filesharing.domain.me"), //Your domain here
            Cache:      autocert.DirCache("certs"),             //Folder for storing certificates
        }
```

and add two A records to the DNS:
[image: dns setup]